# Net Core DataProtection Service throws error 'Error unprotecting key with kid'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have a net6.0 app that's configured the data protection service to persist to sql. I can see the key record being created in db, but on every request there's at least 8-9 of these types of errors in the logs, and each kid is different. I thought the whole point of the data protection service, is that's it's supposed to protect using the key which was persisted, and then it unprotects using same key. The key is then recycled every 90 days. Would appreciate any thoughts on this, as it's spamming our logs.

> Error unprotecting key with kid TheKid.

> Exception:
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {TheKey} was not found in the key ring.

Comment: It may help if you could provide the minimal codes that could reproduce the error

Comment: Where is the DataProtection signing key stored?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1006954/getting-asp-net-core-identity-running-on-azure-lin

Are you using Azure App Service?

> Azure App Service terminates TLS at the load baalncer, and from there
> communicates with your app over HTTP on port 80.
>
> During this flow, a configuration file was being served up from my app
> that included links beginning with "http".
>
> When these links were used by IdentityServer, they were blocked by the
> browser for mixing HTTP and HTTPS requests.
>
> The result of this is that requests to
> "https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration"
> were coming back with content linking to http.

```
"issuer": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/",  
"jwks_uri": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",  
"authorization_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize",  
"token_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/token",  
"userinfo_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/userinfo",  
"end_session_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/endsession",  
"check_session_iframe": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/checksession",  
"revocation_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/revocation",  
"introspection_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/introspect",  
"device_authorization_endpoint": "http://contoso.azurewebsites.net/connect/deviceauthorization",  
"frontchannel_logout_supported": true,  
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,  
"backchannel_logout_supported": true,  
"backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,  
"scopes_supported": [  
    "openid",  
    "profile",  
    "contoso.Web.ServerAPI",  
    "offline_access"  
],
```

How to set all requests as HTTPS in production:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next(context);
    });
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0#when-it-isnt-possible-to-add-forwarded-headers-and-all-requests-are-secure